# show that some pair of 8 points in the unit square will be at most $\sqrt{5}/4$ units apart

Tags: geometry, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

> Show that some pair of 8 points in the unit square will be at most $\sqrt{5}/4$ units apart.

Choose coordinates so that the unit square is centered at the origin. Consider the seven circles with radius $\sqrt{5}/8$ centered at $(\pm 3/8, \pm 1/4), (0, \pm 1/2), (0,0).$ Some two of the two points must lie in the same circle.

> But how would one prove that the circles cover the entire unit square formally?

I know that if two circles intersect, the distance between the centers is less than the sum of their radii. So circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ intersect, where $C_1,C_2$ are centered at $(-3/8, -1/4), (0,-1/2).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An absolutely formal proof that the circles cover the unit square would proceed by *partitioning* the unit square into *convex* polygons, then showing that each polygon has all its vertices within one of the circles (not necessarily on the boundary). Since the polygons are convex, their vertices lying within a circle implies that their whole body (edges and interior) lies within the same circle too.

And you can in fact do a little better by replacing $\frac{\sqrt5}8$ with $\frac1{1+\sqrt7}$ and using this covering:

[image]

If the square is origin-centred, the circle centres are at $(0,0),\left(\pm\frac12,0\right)$ and $\left(\pm\frac14,\pm\frac{2+\sqrt7}{12}\right)$. The proof using the convex partition method is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The first four cover the left and right quarters of the square. The next two cover the middle half. The origin is unnecessary.